# How does sperm gets oxygen in the female reproductive tract?

Tags: human-biology, zoology, reproduction, human-physiology, sexual-reproduction

At the time of insemination, sperm along with seminal plasma enters in female reproductive tract and the plasma contains fructose for providing the energy to sperm
If the fructose follows just EMP pathway (and not further Krebs cycle). Then what's the need of mitochondria. and if it does enters in Citric acid cycle and further performs oxidative phosphorylation, from where does the oxygen comes?

Comment: Do you think it is anaerobic in the reproductive tract? How do you think the cells of the reproductive tract survive?

Comment: Do you think, the cells of female reproductive tract provide oxygen to spermatozoa, well what makes you think that? I wonder if you are considering the glandular secretions to contain dissolved oxygen (do share the references of your idea if possible)

Comment: No, I was thinking more along the lines of where do the cells get there O2 from and why would the spermatozoon be any different?

Comment: Why it wouldn't be different, when a cell is not any association with any tissue fluid, what can be the transporting medium for oxygen from a foreign body of female.

Comment: Kindly upvote the question, for a better reach, Purpose is just to get the query solved asap.

Answer (score -1):

Glycolysis and oxidative respiration are the main sources of ATP production in a sperm which causes oxygen regulating inside the sperm and makes it capable to move itself in the reproductive tract. But, the nutrients required for the survival of sperm are limited **INSIDE THE SPERM.**

But, as it enters the reproductive tract, the female body gives all the nourishment required for the sperm to survive, resulting in increased lifespan of the sperm (4-5 days).

Source: [Oxidative phosphorylation versus glycolysis: what fuel do spermatozoa use?](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4650467/)

Comment: "which causes oxygen regulating inside the sperm" what does it mean? Kindly clarify the source (precise) of oxygen.

Comment: I wrote "OXYGEN" to make you easily understand the process going on. Actually the sperm doesn't require any external oxygen. It is ATP (Adenosine Triphosphate) the energy source that provides the energy required by the sperm to travel to the ova (or the egg). This is the process of ATP formation:  ATP can be formed by 2 processes: oxidative respiration and glycolysis, both of which occur in bovine spermatozoa. Oxidative respiration occurs within the mitochondria, located in the midpiece of the spermatozoon, and results, in the case of glucose, in 36 ATPs being formed per molecule.

Comment: Full Article Source: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.2164/jandrol.107.003533#:~:text=ATP%20can%20be%20formed%20by,ATPs%20being%20formed%20per%20molecule.

Comment: You should first understand the question, before jumping to answer it. Read the question asked.

Comment: Wait, What?? "Sperm doesn't require any external oxygen. ATPs are formed by glycolysis and oxidative respiration". Does your theory says oxidative respiration occurs without oxygen?? and the article, it doesn't holds any relevance related to question.

Comment: "Does your theory says oxidative respiration occurs without oxygen??" I didn't say that sperms don't require ANY oxygen. I said that sperms don't require EXTERNAL OXYGEN. that means the don't require external respiration mechanism. The oxygen formed from ATP synthesis is enough for them to move and fuse with the ova.

Comment: I gave you the source article to make you understand the process of ATP synthesis in Sperms.

Comment: I request you to kindly read the question asked.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to answer. The oxygen required comes from ATP synthesis.

Comment: Does ATP synthesis yields Oxygen?